# Strange behavior of 'chomp' for processing a file line-by-line in Perl

Tags: perl

I am using the following Perl script to do some simple processing:

```
use strict;
my $file = "data-text";
open(FILE, "<$file") or die "Can't open $file: $!\n";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close FILE;
my @arrayA = (); my @arrayB=();
my $i = 0;
while($i < @lines) {
    print $lines[$i], "\t", $lines[$i+1], "\n";
    chomp($lines[$i]); chomp($lines[$i+1]); #The problem is here...
    push @arrayA, \$lines[$i];
    push @arrayB, \$lines[$i+1];
    print $lines[$i], "\t", $lines[$i+1], "\n";
    $i+=2;
}
```

As I indicated in the script, the problem is at the line `chomp($lines[$i]); chomp($lines[$i+1]);`. It seems if I use this line, the lines would be messed up.

What is wrong? Why is this?

Comment: The lines would be messed up how? Also, is it a given that there is an even number of lines in your input file?

Comment: What's the output, exactly, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh I would not expect `chomp` to do anything special except removing the newline characters. Here, it looks like it is removing a lot non-newline characters, as the output tells. Does it matter to have an odd number of lines in the file?

Comment: what is the contents of the input file "data-text"?

Comment: sorry that I cannot share the content of my data file. I just added two lines "what is wrong" and "why is this"in the middle of the text file and copied the results here. I see the same behavior to other lines too. But in any situation, why would I expect such a behavior from chomp?

Comment: Please construct a simple data file that reproduces the problem.  The input, and your expected output are not at all clear.  I ran your script with a two line file, and it seems to work as expected (chomp removes trailing newlines).

Comment: Given an input file with the 2 lines "what is wrong?" and "why is this?" I get the expected results on my machine.  WinXP, ActiveState 5.8.8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chomp` deletes a single `\n` character from the end of a string.

If the string ends with `\r\n` (the Windows-style line ending), `chomp` will leave the `\r` in place.  This would likely result in symptoms similar to what you're seeing.

**EDIT**:

Some background.  Unix-like systems (including Linux) use a single line-feed character (`'\n'`) to mark the end of each line in a text file.  Windows (and its predecessor MS-DOS) uses two characters, a carriage return and a line feed (`\r\n`).

Many of Perl's features are designed to work with text.  Which means, quite reasonably, that Perl assumes by default that any text file it's reading uses the native end-of-line representation of the underlying operating system.

A feature Perl inherited from C is that, when reading a line of text, the native end-of-line sequence, whatever it is, is translated to a single `'\n'` character.  (The reverse translation is done on output).  This frees most programs from having to worry about how text is represented; it's translated to and from a canonical internal form on input and output.  (That form happens to match the Unix format, for historical reasons.)

But that doesn't help much if you need to deal with non-native text files.  If you're running in a Unix-like environment, but reading Windows-format text files, the `\r` characters are going to look like part of the line.  In particular, `chomp` won't do anything special with them.  And when you print a `\r` character, it typically causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the current line without advancing to the next line.  It's a mess.  (Cygwin is a rich source of such confusion; it's a Unix-like environment, using Unix-style text files by default, but it runs under Windows with full visibility to the Windows file system.  Are you using Cygwin?)

See @BillRupert's comment; he's running under Windows with a Windows native implementation of Perl, so he doesn't see the problem you're having.

If you want to deal with non-native text files, you'll need to do a little extra work.  For example, when reading a line of text, rather than just

```
chomp $line;
```

you might write:

```
chomp $line;
$line =~ s/\r$//;
```

And when writing text, you can do this:

```
$line =~ s/$/\r/;
```

But first you'll need to decide whether you want to write the output with Windows-style or Unix-style line endings.  It's tricky.

(There's probably a Perl module that makes this easier; anyone who knows of one, please mention it in a comment.)

Incidentally, the output you're seeing isn't the output your program is producing.  If you filter your output through something that shows non-printable characters in printable form, you'll see `\r` or `^M` in your output.  Use `... | cat -A` or `... | cat -v` if your system has the `cat` command.

If possible, you might consider translating your input before trying to read it.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows style line ending. Can you explain a bit more why this was resulted?

Comment: I see. This is the correct. chomp does not work as expected for this Windows style file. It looked so strange to me and wasted me so much time! Thank you!

Comment: nit: The behaviour isn't actually inherited from C. The C calls made by Perl return \r\n, and Perl does the translation using the :crlf PerlIO layer.

Comment: @ikegami: I meant that it's "inherited: in the sense that the Perl behavior was inspired by C's behavior -- just as Perl inherited curly braces from C.

Comment: Hi Keith, do you mind also explaining why I got `what is why is this?` if `chomp` removed `\n` from `\r\n`? Isn't this strange, even though I now got a working solution?

Comment: @QiangLi: What you probably got was `"what is this?\r\twhy is this?"`.  Printing a '\r` sends the cursor back to the beginning of the current line, and `\t` probably moves the cursor without erasing existing characters.  You'll see this if you pipe the output of your script through `cat -A` (as I already suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your data file I cannot tell for sure, but first of all, let's switch to the modern open and handles, let's use warnings and perhaps just chomp the whole array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

## If line endings are the problem, try for example:
#local $/ = "\r\n";

my $file="data-text";

my @lines;
{
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open $file: $!\n";
    @lines = <$fh>;
}

chomp @lines;

my @arrayA;
my @arrayB;
my $i = 0;
while ($i < @lines) {
    print $lines[$i],"\t",$lines[$i+1],"\n";
    push @arrayA, \$lines[$i];
    push @arrayB, \$lines[$i+1];

    ## The following line is now no different from the above, commented out
    #print $lines[$i],"\t",$lines[$i+1],"\n";
    $i+=2;
}
```

See if that does more what you expect. If you give us (a portion) of the file maybe we could notice something more.

Also if all you are doing is attempting to split every other line to two arrays, you might do:

```
while (@lines) {
    my $line1 = shift @lines;
    my $line2 = shift(@lines) || '';
    print $line1,"\t",$line2,"\n";
    push @arrayA, $line1;
    push @arrayB, $line2;
}
```

Which has less memory usage.

Comment: I still got `what is why is this?` for my original input. I am just not sure what is going on here. Very strange to me too. Maybe it is the input file? But what kind of input value can cause this strange behavior?

Comment: was the file created on one platform (Mac, Win, Linux) then acted on on a different platform. If so then its the line endings. You will need to do a line ending conversion or some other trick.

Comment: if the line ending is the problem add `local $/ = "\r\n";` near the top of the file, say just after `use warnings`

Comment: Yes, thank you Joel for the time and efforts. I myself wasted so much time without noticing it is the \r\n issue.