# Does Perl correctly handle Windows-style line endings in source code on Solaris?

Tags: perl, solaris

Does Perl correctly handle Windows-style line endings in source code on Solaris? In other words, if a Perl script has a `^M` at the end of a line will perl parse it correctly when it's run on a Solaris machine?

```
if(/fmr_dest/) { 
    do_traffic($dbc, 'rprice', '-MSG_RESP', $customer_no, $data{$customer_no}{$action_type});
    next;
}

if(/fmr_rate/) { ## Change to customer rates^M
    do_traffic($dbc, 'rprice', '-MSG_RESP', $customer_no, $data{$customer_no}{$action_type});^M
    next;^M
}^M

if(/conn/) {
    ...
```

Comment: What has your testing shown you so far?

Comment: The lines not containing ^M do not appear affected by the carriage returns

Comment: The ^M made it into a script in production and I am looking to confirm it is ok.  My colleague thinks it is ok but I am just double checking.

Comment: Define "parse it correctly"

Comment: Run it as if it weren't there

Comment: I can think of at least one possible issue: if you have a multi-line string literal that your code expects to contain a newline, but not a carriage return.

Comment: Thanks.  The statements are just plain ones.  I added them to the question.

Comment: They're whitespace characters, so they should have no effect in any place where an extra space character wouldn't have an effect.

Comment: Another trick, if you use vi/vim,  is do `:set ff=unix`

Comment: Ok perfect - if they would be just like a space then it will work fine.

Comment: I made a short script and replaced *all* of the non-quoted spaces (except in the shebang line) with CRs. It ran the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifact carriage returns (`\r`) in your script will ruin your day in at least two ways:

1. As ThisSuitIsBlackNot pointed out in a comment, there will be confusion between what your multi-line strings contain and what it looks like they contain -- this affects line lengths, the behavior of `chomp` and `chop`, multi-line regular expression matching, string comparisons, etc.
2. More seriously, [a carriage return at the end of your shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556524) (`#!/usr/bin/perl\r`) will cause the shell to be unable to execute your script directly, as it will look for a program called `"/usr/bin/perl" . chr(10)` to interpret it.

Artifact carriage returns in your program input [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784307) [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384725/unexpected-result-of-string-concatenation/25384807#25384807) [come](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771314/perl-code-output-not-displayed-properly/29771381#29771381) [back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971527/print-perl-string-with-question-mark/16971552#16971552) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010764/extra-unexpected-characters-perl/31011102) [bite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292212/rogue-character-in-tab-delimited-file-causing-error/9292244#9292244) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841047/strange-behavior-of-chomp-for-processing-a-file-line-by-line-in-perl/7841339#7841339).